# JS function to fill an array with unique elements thorugh generated values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some simple browser game using p5.js. And i've ran into a problem:

I have an array of zombies. Zombie object has a method getanswer() which returns a number. I'm trying to make a function addzombie(), which pushes one new Zombie to the array. The problem is that i don't want any repetitive answers in the array. This is my current function:

```
function mkex(){
    var values = []
    for (i=1;i<11;i++){
        values.push(i);
    }
    var signs = ['+','-','/','*'];
    var result = -1;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var sign1 = "";
    var sign2 = "";
    while (result<=0){
        a = values[Math.round(Math.random()*(values.length-1))];
        b = values[Math.round(Math.random()*(values.length-1))];
        c = values[Math.round(Math.random()*(values.length-1))];
        sign1 = signs[Math.round(Math.random()*(signs.length-1))];
        sign2 = signs[Math.round(Math.random()*(signs.length-1))];
        switch(sign1){
            case "+":
                switch(sign2){
                    case "+":
                        result=a+b+c;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result=a+b-c;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (b%c==0){
                            result=a+b/c;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result=a+b*c;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "-":
                switch(sign2){
                    case "+":
                        result=a-b+c;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result=a-b-c;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (b%c==0){
                            result=a-b/c;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result=a-b*c;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "/":
                switch(sign2){
                    case "+":
                        if (a%b==0){
                            result=a/b+c;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        if (a%b==0){
                            result=a/b-c;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (a%b==0){
                            if (a/b%c==0){
                                result=a/b/c;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        if (a%b==0){
                            result=a/b*c;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                switch(sign2){
                    case "+":
                        result=a*b+c;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result=a*b-c;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (a*b%c==0){
                            result=a*b/c;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result=a*b*c;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    var expr = ""+a+sign1+b+sign2+c;
    var ret = [expr, result];
    return ret;
}


function addzombie(){
    var expr = mkex();
    if (zombies.length==0){
        zombies.push(new Zombie(player.getxy(),expr));
    } else{
        for (i=0;i<zombies.length;i++){
            if (zombies[i].getanswer()==expr[1]){
                addzombie();
            }
        zombies.push(new Zombie(player.getxy(),expr));
    }
}
```

The mkex() function returns an array containing a string and an answer. Zombie needs player's coordinates to spawn it away from the player.

This function doesn't work, i still have zombies with same answers. Could someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: **First of all:** You are using a global `i` and recursion at the same time => **bad**. **Secondly:** this could recurse for ever (well, untill you run out of stack and get an error) depending on how `mkex` works.

Comment: OK. i got it about the for loop, thanks a lot. How can i perform this task not recursively?

Comment: you want to put the unique values, push if zombie is not there else not.

Comment: How does `mkex` work? Where is its code.

Comment: I've updated the post an added the mkex() code. Thanks for your involvement!

Comment: You should really stop using global vars: `for( var i;...`.

Comment: Alright, i got your lesson (var is global, let is local), thank you very much. I'm a newbie in JS. Don't judge me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Set` to keep track of the answers would make the solution simpler and faster (since average search time in `Set` is `O(1)`)

```
let answerSet = new Set();
let zombies = [];

function addZombie() {
  let expr = mkex();
  let zombie = new Zombie(player.getxy(),expr);

  while(answerSet.has(zombie.getanswer())) {
    zombie = new Zombie(player.getxy(),expr);
  }

  answerSet.add(zombie.getanswer());
  zombies.push(zombie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for hinting the Set. I've used it and everything worked like a charm.